# VBA: Event for triggered Events

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking to see if there is an Events trigger for well... Events. I'm making an idle timeout function and the thought of having to call my function for every procedure seems a bit unnecessary. More specifically OnClick events. I do have an `DoEvents` loop that is constantly going. I there a way to find what is being triggered via `DoEvents`? Or DoEvents Returns what Event is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be *WithEvents* - poorly documented but quite handy. Recently, I wrote an article on a different subject where WithEvents proved extremely useful:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html)

It also contains a link to a tutorial by John Colby.

Comment: This is perfect. Is there anymore information on `WithEvents` that you can link me?

Comment: Only old stuff, I believe. Here is one by my good friend _Shamil Salakhetdinov_: [Using Dynamic External Event Procedures](http://www.vb123.com.au/199901_ss_event.htm). And another: [Programming WithEvents](http://www.vb123.com.au/199812_mk_events.htm)